# How to sort by an associated column in this active record query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I need a few queries sorted by an associated model. I have a list of Customers that I get and I need to make sure the customer list is sorted by the last Message they received. Here are the current queries:

```
  @open_customers = @company.customers.open.includes(:last_received_message)
  @your_customers = current_user.customers.includes(:last_message)
  @sidebar_customers = current_company.customers.open_or_claimed.
    where("user_id = ? OR user_id IS NULL", current_user.id).
    order(aasm_state: :asc).includes([:last_received_message, :user])
```

these are three separate queries.

@open_customers needs to be sorted by the created_at of last_received_message
@your_customers needs to be sorted by the created_at of last_message
@sidebar_customers needs to be sorted by the created_at of last_received_message

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You might try checking out Section 14: **scopes** here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html

Also this website has a course called **Rails 4 Outlaws** that does a great job teaching scopes: https://www.codeschool.com